# Is 5D good as a second body beside a 5D mark II?

Tags: body, event

I own a 5D mark II and I do event photography. I have numbers of lenses in my collection and that's the reason I am looking for a second body, because changing lenses in event is a real pain. Do you think a 5D will be good as a second body beside 5D mark II? Or do you suggest a crop body?

Comment: Can't answer on the basis of the brief details you gave already.  How much do you use telephoto lenses?   How important is the weight of the body?  Which lenses do you mostly use?

Comment: As I've said I mostly do event photography, so 135 f/2 L, 24-105 f/4 L IS, 70-200 f/2.8 L IS II, 50 f/1.4 and 85 f/1.8 are my daily gears. 

As I already have a 5D mark II, so weight is perfectly fine. Handheld situations are ok too :)

Comment: What sorts of events? Lighting (and therefore low light support) is going to be very different at a gymkhana to a night club...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you looking for in your second body?

1. Backup in case first body fails?
2. Ability to use two cameras a once; One with a 135 f/2 one with a 50 f/1.4?
3. Ability to use same lens on different camera but get a different look?
4. Ability to use same lens on different camera but get the same look?

You need and choice of a 2nd body may change depending on your answers.  I think a 5D would be a great 2nd body, but so would a 7D or maybe even the cheapest available Canon (in your case) SLR.

Answer (score 4):

With the advent of the 5D mkIII and the subsequent price reduction on the mkII, I think I would be buying a 5D mkII instead. The biggest reason would be comparable output, though if you had the money, a mkIII and mkII combo would be better. Net effect, the original 5D is simply passed by and I wouldn't consider it.

As an aside, I made a similar decision with the Pentax K-5. At first I was dual shooting with the K-5 and K20D, but the limitations in the K20D became way too obvious and I sold it off and bought a second K-5 instead. My sense is that you'll run into the same basic issue with the 5D options, so don't spend the money, you won't recover it.

Comment: See, I'd see the release of the 5D3 as an excuse to make the 5D2 the backup, and get the newer model :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  When I moved from film to digital, I started with a 5D.  It's a fantastic camera and would make an excellent 2nd camera or backup.  I use mine for the latter.